# Is Neowise viewable from my position?

Tags: amateur-observing, comets

I have had an impossible time trying to locate this comet. My lat/long is 38.3/-82.4. My elevation is 705ft.

The application that I'm using shows me exactly where Neowise is supposed to be (North East, best viewed before sunrise around 4:00am, etc.), but I've managed to not locate it once in the last three days at that time. Stayed out for an hour straight each time, starting at 4:00am.

Is it not viewable from my position?

Comment: 4am sounds like it's getting day already and contrast fading rapidly. It is more the time I stopped observing it. Try earlier? look for capella and then look a bit more west (10° or so) and slightly down

Comment: Dr. Becky to the rescue! [How to spot Comet NEOWISE, plus the largest 3D map of the Universe | Night Sky News July 20](https://youtu.be/RbZ13TEHuOs)

Answer (score 2):

From [that location](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/usa/huntington-wv), the easiest time in the morning to see the comet is between 4:50 and 5:10 AM EDT.
I've seen it at similar times relative to [nautical dawn](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/different-types-twilight.html) at my location.
Much earlier than that, the comet may be too low, especially if nearby trees obscure the horizon.
Some software mishandles daylight saving time.

As the comet shifts eastward, nautical dusk around 10:00 PM will be a good time in the evening to look for it.
This [Sky & Telescope article](https://skyandtelescope.org/press-releases/new-bright-visitor-comet-neowise/) provides both morning and evening finder charts.

Comment: I'll see if I can find it again. I've been exclusively up at that time (wrecked my sleep schedule for this) and haven't had any luck. Thanks for the info.

Comment: *Was* between 4:50 and 5:10 AM . The comet is currently transitioning from being a pre-sunrise comet to a post-sunset comet.

Comment: We, a friend and I, can't spot Neowise by the naked eyes. However, using a smartphone with a ported gcam in astrophotography mode gives a more then decent result. I wanted to post the pic but this would require this comment to be listed as an answer...